# graphics.h not opening the BGI executable

Tags: c++, bgi

When I run this program:

```
#include <graphics.h>

int main()
{
   int gd = DETECT, gm;
   int x = 320, y = 240, radius;

   initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\\TC\\BGI");

   for ( radius = 25; radius <= 125 ; radius = radius + 20)
      circle(x, y, radius);

   getch();
   closegraph();
   return 0;
}
```

It isn't oppening an 2nd application that must be the BGI and on the screen shows me this. [Open Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0m3t1.png)

I also get a warning that says:

```
**||=== Build: Debug in a (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\MIHAI\Desktop\a\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\Users\MIHAI\Desktop\a\main.cpp|8|warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]|
||=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
||=== Run: Debug in a (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
**
```

How can I fix this and run the program??

Comment: initgraph() is a C function that is very, very old and does not use `const char*` for the 3rd argument.  The warning is benign and does not cause this crash.  Debugging this ancient library is going to take you a while, knowing how to use a debugger is a primary requirement.  Consider to move to the next project.

Comment: Start with checking whether `initgraph` succeeds.